# Django edit the owner of Object

Tags: python, django

When an object is called via URL, I want to change the owner(user) of the object. The owner in my case is a ForeignKey.

I tried it with something like this, which of course doesn't work

```
def ChangeField(request, title_id):
    user_title = Field.objects.filter(id=title_id,
                                      user=request.user)
    if user_title:
        user_title.user = 'Admin'
        user_title.save()
    else:
        return redirect('https://example.com')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/another')
```

When the user of object ID 11 for example calls the URL /11, I want to change the owner of object 11 to the superuser, I mey case the superuser is called 'Admin'

Models File

```
class Field(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        default=None,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    ....
```

Comment: Do you have multiple superuser ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `user_title.user = request.user`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get`  instead of `filter` and set `superuser` as

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def ChangeField(request, title_id):
    try:
        user_title = Field.objects.get(id=title_id,
                                      user=request.user)
         superuser = User.objects.get(is_superuser=True) # I assumed here one superuser you can get which superuser with your own condition here
         user_title.user = superuser
         user_title.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/another') # return response after successful 
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return redirect('https://example.com') # return response if object does not exists
```